# What is the package name of this Through Hole LED?

Tags: led, identification

[image: LED in mystery package]

Does anyone know the name of this package type for an LED?  Does anyone know where I can get one like this in red?

Answer (score 2):

It is just a radial through-hole style. Here is one of many red ones I found on digikey.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LTL-709E/160-1084-ND/153446

Answer (score 0):

If it is about 3.3mm x 2.4mm, then distributers call them 'T-3/4', add 'through-hole' (or 'thru-hole') to the search and you'll find plenty.

For example [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=204192+110155305+110166275&Ns=P_PRICE_FARNELL_UK%7C0&locale=en_UK&appliedparametrics=true&getResults=true&suppressRedirect=true&isRedirect=&No=0&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=204192+110155305+110243773+110166275&mm=1002877||,1002665||,&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=false&originalQueryURL=%2Fjsp%2Fsearch%2Fbrowse.jsp%3FN%3D204192%26No%3D0%26getResults%3Dtrue%26appliedparametrics%3Dtrue%26locale%3Den_UK%26divisionLocale%3Den_UK%26catalogId%3D%26skipManufacturer%3Dfalse%26skipParametricAttributeId%3D%26prevNValues%3D204192)

or [google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=T-3/4+LEDs&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22T-3%2F4%22+LEDs&rls=en)

Lots of distributers sell them.